# Docker build Gentoo operation not permitted

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, gentoo

I have a docker-compose with this container to build Gentoo

```
default:
    build: docker/gentoo
    hostname: default.jpo.net
```

My Dockerfile to setup Gentoo in multi-stage build is

```
FROM gentoo/portage as portage

FROM gentoo/stage3-amd64

COPY --from=portage /usr/portage /usr/portage

RUN emerge --jobs $(nproc) -qv www-servers/apache net-misc/curl net-misc/openssh

RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ''
RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N ''
RUN sed -i 's/#PubkeyAuthentication/PubkeyAuthentication/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && chmod 700 /root/.ssh && touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN wget -O telegraf.tar.gz http://get.influxdb.org/telegraf/telegraf-0.11.1-1_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
    && tar xvfz telegraf.tar.gz \
    && rm telegraf.tar.gz \
    && mv /usr/lib/telegraf /usr/lib64/telegraf \
    && rm -rf /usr/lib && ln -s /usr/lib64 /usr/lib

ADD telegraf.conf /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf

COPY entrypoint.sh /
COPY infinite_curl.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /entrypoint.sh /infinite_curl.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["telegraf", "-config", "/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf"]
```

The problem is the build fail during the `emerge` command when it setup packages.

Then I get this error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
 * ERROR: dev-libs/apr-1.5.2::gentoo failed (install phase):
 *   dodoc failed
```

I tried adding `privileged=true` in my docker-compose file and with adding `USER root` inside my Dockerfile without success.

I also tried to use the last version of `openssh` without success too.
I searched the Internet but I haven't found anything successfull.

Docker version

```
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

Docker-compose version

```
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and this build work well on Ubuntu 17.10 with same docker/docker-compose versions

Do you have some clues ?

Comment: and if you run docker-compose as root?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Same error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at in `src-install()` for that [ebuild](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo/blob/master/dev-libs/apr/apr-1.5.2.ebuild), this appears to be a bug upstream.

> # Prallel install breaks since apr-1.5.1
>
> #make -j1 DESTDIR="${D}" install || die

There are several [two bugs](https://bugs.gentoo.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=apr%20parallel) related to building apr in parallel.